# React pop up modal to install PWA

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, progressive-web-apps

Hello I'm currently implementing an `add to home screen` modal when I first load my page.

I wanted to put this inside my modal if the app detects that it is on desktop.[image]

But when my app detects that it is an IOS mobile. it will show like this

---

[image]

My code

```
const MasterIndexPage = () => {


const classes = useStyles()

  const [userAgent, setUserAgent] = useState('')
  const [isAndroid, setIsAndroid] = useState(false)
  const [isApple, setIsApple] = useState(false)
  const [isWindows, setIsWindows] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {
      setIsAndroid(true)
    } else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPod/i)) {
      setIsApple(true)
    } else {
      setIsWindows(true)
    }
  }, [])

return (
  <section>{isApple && <Test />}</section>
 )
}


const Test = () => {


 const classes = useStyles()

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true)

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
        className={classes.modal}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        closeAfterTransition
        BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
        BackdropProps={{
          timeout: 500,
        }}
      >
        <div id="popup">
          <h4 className="h4_addtohome">
            Add Our App?<span className="popup-close-icon">&times;</span>
          </h4>
          <p className="p__addtohome">
            Tap below to add an icon to your home screen for quick access!
          </p>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  )
}
```

How can I put the install pop up inside the modal when my page load. And I want also to only pop up my modal only on the first load.

Comment: You have no control as regards to the pop to install a PWA. The browser determines that.

Answer (score 1):

Capture the installation event from browser and just insert an install button inside your modal that will trigger the prompt() method on click. See more in the link https://web.dev/learn/pwa/installation-prompt/